# Commandline "Pack" built application into ClickOnce setup?

Tags: winforms, command-line, build, clickonce, publish

**Situation:**

- Windows Forms application built using **/target:Build**
- If possible, I want to avoid using the **/target:Publish**
- Available in a particular OutputPath, say: **"C:\Temp\ClickOnce"**
- I want to pack it all up via **command line** to **ClickOnce** setup package.
- **Any way to do it?**

In time:

*I am using TFS and what I'm looking for is to avoid changing the .xaml (build workflow) and do the whole thing via powershell (PostBuild script).*

Any help?

Comment: I have came accross a tool called **[mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx)** , now I'm checking about it. Will edit later if I find an answer for it.

Comment: *mage* is for signing files. *msbuild* is the only command-line tool capable to create the ClickOnce setup.